# Which planet is Leviathan on?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Ok so I'm a bit of a wimp and didn't want to fry Ann Bryson's brain after she was so willing to let Leviathan take control of her. I stopped at nose bleeding, which has given me a variety of different locations throughout the galaxy and quite a large search grid for Leviathan's possible location.

Problem is, this is an 'end of game' save, so all of this entire region is swarming with Reapers - each system is taking multiple attempts to do a full scan as I'm having to keep diving out of the system to lose them.

Which planet is Leviathan on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After completing this mission, a new system of planets opens up in a system called Sigurd's Cradle in the north of the Galaxy Map. Within this system there is a star called Psi Tophet, which has three planets in orbit.

The first of these planets is called 2181 Despoina;

[image]

This is a planet covered nearly entirely in water, with a small detectable structure on the surface in the middle of the ocean. Land here to begin the final stages of the search for Leviathan.